# how to route forwarding on respberry

Tags: raspberry-pi3, wifi

This is the respberry 3

wlan0 is built-in network card to link web
enxe84e0638ecb6 is external network adapter to route forwarding

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"PandoraBox_00166C"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 20:76:93:00:16:68   
          Bit Rate=13 Mb/s   Tx-Power=1496 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

enxe84e0638ecb6  unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use config.txt in /boot.